# Adobe CS 5.5 place for fonts

Tags: flash, adobe-creative-suite

Where Adobe CS 5.5 (trial) stores fonts? I already added to `%windir%\fonts` folder these two fonts (yes, same name font (ttf)), but still when I want to open  *.fla, dialog prompt still shown that fonts are missing:

[image]

Win 7, 64bit

adding font folder to `%commonfiles%\Adobe\Fonts` solving only one font, see:
[image]

Output of cmd, what asked and31415:
[image]

Second output:
[image]

Comment: Try placing the fonts in the `%commonprogramfiles%\Adobe\Fonts` folder. Create the folder yourself in case it doesn't exist already.

Comment: Strange... this advice just solved one font, but remains second- see edited question top.

Comment: Try running this command in a command prompt and post here the output: `cd /d %systemdrive% & dir TheMix*.ttf /b /s`

Comment: I give you output of your commands to first of my post (initial question of this topic- because there is photo uploader...)

Comment: Run this command too: `cd /d "%windir%\Fonts" & dir TheMix*.ttf /b` To easily copy the actual command output, right-click an empty area in the command prompt choose **Mark** from the context menu. The select the text you want to copy, and press Enter when you're done.

Comment: Thx for your advice about copy text from cmd prompt, I know it, but prefer edit first post- because there is easy image uploader and text formater bar with functions. Still dont understand how to format code in small reply box there in thread...

Comment: please anyone know?

Comment: Try removing all copies of those fonts, restart, and install them again. Make sure the `Fonts` folder contains a single copy for each `.ttf` file.

Comment: If I were you, I'd try reinstalling Adobe CS. It appears that something went wrong in the installation and where it finds the fonts. I'm not entirely sure why this is happening but this might help.